# Spring Boot Enable SSL for private pages

Tags: spring-mvc, ssl, https, spring-security, spring-boot

In my spring boot web app I have some public pages and few admin pages. Admin pages are secured by spring security.
I need to enable SSL/HTTPs for login page and post login admin pages.
SSL is not required for public pages.

I have  enabled ssl in application.properties as below

```
server.port = 8444
server.ssl.key-store = classpath:keystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password = secret
server.ssl.key-password = another-secret
```

and added another connector in config class

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
    tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(initiateHttpConnector());
    return tomcat;
}

private Connector initiateHttpConnector() {
    Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
    connector.setScheme("http");
    connector.setPort(80);
    connector.setSecure(false);
    connector.setRedirectPort(8444);
    return connector;
}
```

and part of my security config

```
    @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
           String[] securedUrls = { "/app/**" };
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(securedUrls).hasAnyRole("SYSADMIN")
.and().requiresChannel().antMatchers(securedUrls).requiresSecure().and()
    .requiresChannel().antMatchers("/login").requiresSecure();
                            http.formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/app", true).successHandler(myAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
.failureHandler(myAuthenticationFailureHandler).and().logout();
    }
```

I am able to browse public pages, once I load the login page I get error in chrome as " This webpage has a redirect loop  ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error when my domain name was referenced without a preceding 'www.'